# How to lowercase nested relation field in Laravel Eloquent query?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have a search mechanism like this, with "client.partner" nested relation:

```
$query->whereHas("client.partner", function ($query) use ($searchterm, $relation) {
    $query->when($relation === "contains", function ($query) use ($searchterm, $relation) {
        $query->where("partners.name", "LIKE", "%" . strtolower($searchterm) . "%");
    });   
});
```

The question is, that how "partners.name" in where clause can be lowercased.

I tried to use LOWER() function, as follows, but it did not work:

```
...
 $query->where(LOWER("partners.name"), "LIKE", "%" . strtolower($searchterm) . "%");
...
```

Any idea?

Comment: do `whereRaw('lower('partners.name')`

Answer (score 0):

In the meantime I realized how to do it. For someone who has similar problem:

$query->when($relation === "contains", function ($query) use ($searchterm, $relation) {$query->where(DB::raw("LOWER(partners.name)"), "LIKE", "%" . $searchterm . "%");
});